# Centering hyperlinks inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have got this css:

```
#footerLinks {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;   
}

#footerLinks a {
    float: left;
    color: #c2c2c2;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

And this html:

```
<div id="footerLinks">
    <a href="">No Porn on App Store</a>
    <a href="">Porn and Apple</a>
    <a href="">iPhone Porn Wiki</a>
</div>
```

The problem is that the hyperlinks wont be in the center of the page. I tried `margin: auto`, `text-align` and tried to play with the `margins` nothing works, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `float:left;` and `display:block;` from this class

```
#footerLinks a {                
    color:#c2c2c2;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/364rL/)

Comment: but now, they all appear one under another

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd did you remove display:block;? check the demo I posted

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd a element is default inline element you don't have to specify :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your css.

```
#footerLinks {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;   
}

#footerLinks a {
    color: #c2c2c2;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```